# Do not see run as script / run as web page option in PHP perspective

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt, eclipse-juno

I am using Eclipse Juno with PDT version 3.1.1.201209241501. I am trying to debug my PHP web page but i do not see the options to Debug As or Run As - Php webpage *or* Debug As or Run As PhP Script. I am using PhP 5.3.18

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

When you click on debug configuration the you should be able to select PHP CLI application or PHP Web application.

If you can't see it, it looks PDT is not correctly installed, my PDT says version -   PHP Development Tools (PDT) SDK Feature   3.1.1.201209101312
and should be latest version for Windows.

Have you configured PHP executable in Preferences->PHP->PHP executables?

Comment: Thanks for the answer - i finally figured out my problem with debugging yesterday. I mentioned that i am using PhP 5.3.18. Well i am using a thread safe version. Zend do not have a corresponding TS (thread safe) binary for this version of PHP and therefore I could not debug using it. That was my real problem.

Comment: Ok, try to use Xdebug I find it better the ZendDebugger (for example support for profiling).